# Add hover events to a vertex in mxGraph

Tags: javascript, hover, dom-events, mxgraph

Is there any way to handle hover events on vertices? I don't see anything relevant, such as `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `mouseover`, etc, in mxEvents or any of the examples, so I'm assuming no. (Are there any other crafty workarounds?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [hoverstyle](https://doc.jgraph.com/javascript/examples/hoverstyle.html) example demonstrates how to implement this. This specific code relevant to the question:

```
        // Changes fill color to red on mouseover
        graph.addMouseListener(
        {
            currentState: null,
            previousStyle: null,
            mouseDown: function(sender, me)
            {
                if (this.currentState != null)
                {
                    this.dragLeave(me.getEvent(), this.currentState);
                    this.currentState = null;
                }
            },
            mouseMove: function(sender, me)
            {
                if (this.currentState != null && me.getState() == this.currentState)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var tmp = graph.view.getState(me.getCell());

                // Ignores everything but vertices
                if (graph.isMouseDown || (tmp != null && !
                    graph.getModel().isVertex(tmp.cell)))
                {
                    tmp = null;
                }

                if (tmp != this.currentState)
                {
                    if (this.currentState != null)
                    {
                        this.dragLeave(me.getEvent(), this.currentState);
                    }

                    this.currentState = tmp;

                    if (this.currentState != null)
                    {
                        this.dragEnter(me.getEvent(), this.currentState);
                    }
                }
            },
            mouseUp: function(sender, me) { },
            dragEnter: function(evt, state)
            {
                if (state != null)
                {
                    this.previousStyle = state.style;
                    state.style = mxUtils.clone(state.style);
                    updateStyle(state, true);
                    state.shape.apply(state);
                    state.shape.reconfigure();
                }
            },
            dragLeave: function(evt, state)
            {
                if (state != null)
                {
                    state.style = this.previousStyle;
                    updateStyle(state, false);
                    state.shape.apply(state);
                    state.shape.reconfigure();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: To what reference `this.` in each events ? I'm trying to write this with arrow functions

Comment: @An-droid based on the code, `this` is the object passed into the `addMouseListener` function